# The operator < is undefined for the arguments T

Tags: java

Estuve practicando para una prueba de Estructuras de datos y me encontré con el problema del titulo, cómo se puede volver T en un comparable?

```java
public class Nodo<T> {
    T dato;
    Nodo<T> siguiente;
    public Nodo(T dato) {
        super();
        this.dato = dato;
    }

}
```

Aquí la clase lista, pero creo que el problema es de la clase nodo; pero no estoy totalmente seguro de esto

```
public class Lista<T> {
    Nodo<T> primero;

    void insertar(T nuevo_Dato) {
        Nodo<T> nuevo= new Nodo<T>(nuevo_Dato);
        if (primero==null){
            primero=nuevo;
        }else{
            if(nuevo_Dato<primero){//aqui es donde me sale el error

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pero para que le pones esto `<>` a la derecha del nomrbe de la **Clase** que pretendes hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer que T sea comparable sería algo como:

```java
public class Nodo<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T dato;
    Nodo<T> siguiente;
    public Nodo(T dato) {
        super();
        this.dato = dato;
    }

}
```

Con lo que se está indicando que T implementa la interfaz Comparable. 
La clase Lista podría quedar algo como:

```java
public class Lista<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    Nodo<T> primero;

    void insertar(T nuevo_Dato) {
        Nodo<T> nuevo= new Nodo<>(nuevo_Dato);
        if (primero==null){
            primero=nuevo;
        }else{
            if(nuevo_Dato.compareTo(primero.dato)<0){//aqui es donde me sale el error
          //  


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no tenía ni idea de la existencia de esa interfaz